# How to setup nginx cache for script-generated images?

Tags: caching, nginx

I have a script, that generates and outputs images directly (uses http://glide.thephpleague.com/).

All images are served from `/img/`.

How can I configure NGINX to cache them, bypass the script and serve images directly?

E.g. it should catch response from script, put the image somewhere (the best if on a separate server) and serve directly on subsequent requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to provide your nginx config if you'd like a more complete answer.

Following the standard cache setup found [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/) should do the trick. If you're serving files out of the `/img/` always, then you could do the following:

```
location ^~ /img/ {
    alias /absolute/path/to/img/folder;
    expires 31d; #or whatever you prefer
    add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    error_page 404 = @your_upstream_generating_the_files;
}
```

What this does is it first checks the `/img/` folder if the file is there. If it is not, you want to pass it to your application so that it can generate it for you. Next time the resource is requested, it will serve it out of the `/img/` folder.